# Facebook plugins are shifting to the right outside of their boundaries

Tags: facebook

I have been steadily working on my website for a few months now and I noticed earlier today that my facebook like box and the facebook buttons on the sidebar have all moved to the right. They all appear to be outside of the wrapper that contains everything too which is strange. Here are some screenshots of what I am talking about:

- Like Box: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cGJ26.jpg
- Sidebar: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2yO9n.png

I didn't change anything on my website and I also checked it on four of the major browsers:

- IE: The sidebar and like box are both shifted to the right, and there are other errors - but it is IE after all.
- Firefox: Both the sidebar and like box are shifted to the right.
- Safari: Both of them are fine and in the right spot.
- Chrome: The like box is shifted to the right but the sidebar is fine.

I have spent a few hours trying to see if anyone else was having this problem and also to see if there was something wrong with my css but have had no luck. If anyone can shed some light on this problem I would greatly appreciate it! Here is my website encase you need to check out the problem for yourself: www. dogfactsdaily.com/

Comment: I have this problem too. Just happened today. I'm afraid I have no answer either, just hoping they fix it!

Comment: Has anyone found a solution to this yet, it's really annoying!!

Answer (score 0):

OK, after a while of being annoyed about this I decided to do the sensible thing and check the FB Social Plugins Page.

Having updated my code to use the new HTML5 code generated here:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/recommendations/

It is now behaving proeprly again!